# Item no longer reviewable on ended Help and Improvement review

Tags: bug, review-queues, help-improvement

I've just reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32181447/3453226) through the [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) review queue.

After hitting <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>, it didn't say:

> Thanks for your edit!

But:

> This item is no longer reviewable.

Changes were saved but I cannot find it in my review history.

Comment: Assumption: While you were doing your edit, someone flagged the question as VLQ and/or voted to close as off-topic, removing it from the queue.

Comment: Was [this the same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32181447/2) that you were making through the help queue? Or did you edit it on the post directly after it wouldn't let you do it in the help queue?

Comment: @CRABOLO It did let me do it in the queue. Look at the revision summary: [it's been added separately as a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181447/find-minimum-in-sorted-array-which-was-shifted#comment52251661_32181447) by the review system.